# Account association bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts

I recently opened an account over at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. I associated my account there with my account here. I then opened CStheory again, and I got a red banner saying "You've associated your Theoretical Computer Science and Theoretical Computer Science accounts: +100 reputation". I made a printscreen in case it turns out to be useful.

This is obviously a bug. I'm almost sure this 100 rep was intended to be awarded to the account I just created. My account on this site gained 100 rep (I went from 358 to 458).

**Edit**: I tried reassociating all my accounts as per Tsuyoshi Ito's answer, which gave the missing 100 rep to my Programming account. I still have 100 too much rep on my CStheory account though.

Comment: +1 for honesty (and also for finding a funny message “You've associated your Theoretical Computer Science and Theoretical Computer Science accounts: +100 reputation”).

Comment: The message was hilarious - unfortunately it wasn't quite so hilarious that I was unable to post my answer here (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/17824//18853#18853) because it contained more than one hyperlink due to insufficient rep...

Comment: I read your edit.  Yes, it is a bug.  However, it may not be so bad because you may soon get 200 rep points (that is, 100 to go) on programmers.stackexchange.com, in which case effectively you only received the bonus on cstheory.stackexchange.com a little earlier than it was supposed to be.

Comment: Probably the same issue as the one described on the following pages: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/did-not-get-100-rep-for-account-assosiation, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100.

Comment: The same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57462/is-reputation-100-for-having-at-least-200-on-another-site-retroactive/57463#57463) by Jaydles on Meta Stack Overflow suggests that you may be able to recover the lost +100 bonus by **deassociating and reassociating** your accounts.  Note that [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work/5930#5930) by Daniel Moura to another question states that you have to start the reassociation on the site where you have ≥200 rep points to get +100 bonus.

The situation in the questions on Meta is certainly different from yours, so be warned that there might be an unexpected consequence.  You may want to bring the issue to Meta Stack Overflow so that more people familiar with the SE systems can give you an advice.

Comment: By the way, I tried this “deassociate and reassociate” thing because I knew that I had associated my account on math.stackexchange.com too early to get the +100 bonus.  A pleasant surprise was that I received the +100 bonus also on this site (which was reasonable in retrospect).  So my thanks to Alex ten Brink whose question gave me the opportunity to reclaim two +100 bonuses. :)

Comment: And thanks to you for fixing half the bug: I managed to get the 100 rep for my new account trying this out.